# Controlling a Raspberry Pi from a Chrome Extension

Tags: ssh, remote

I am working on a project where I need to be able to issue shell commands to a Raspberry Pi 3 through a Chrome extension (that I will be writing). At the moment, I am able ping and SSH to the Pi from my laptop, which is connected directly to the Pi with an Ethernet cable in crossover configuration.

The next step of connecting from a Chrome extension is the part I'm having difficulty with. Most of the information I found about SSH-ing from Chrome pertained to apps, but for this project an extension would be much more appropriate. What approaches can I use to control the Pi from an extension?

(SSH or other secure protocol would be ideal, but I'm open to other suggestions as well.)

Comment: A news appeared at the (great) http://linux-projects.org few days ago said that it will be soon possible to control the screen & mouse & keyboard and even audio from the browser with NO extensions or plug'in. This is the original news: http://www.linux-projects.org/2016/10/09/unique-upcoming-projects/ . So you will be able to control your terminal from the browser.Edit: if you are wondering about encryption: yes, it's everything encrypted in the channel rpi<->browser

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46870/discussion-on-question-by-tlng05-controlling-a-raspberry-pi-from-a-chrome-extens).

Comment: https://github.com/mimecuvalo/firessh